# The same current_user on multiple models in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

### Problem

I have a User model, and the Volunteer model that inherits from the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Volunteer < User
end
```

They are both saved on the same table in the database, but have different controllers / routes.

The routes are:

```
devise_for :users ....
devise_for :volunteers ....
```

And this works fine and dandy, but the authorization system that I use depends on a `current_user` helper. And this fails for volunteers because devise creates `current_volunteer` for the Volunteer model.

What i have tried is to set `devise_for :volunteers, :singular => "user"`, and this creates a current_user that refers to users and volunteers, but the problem now is that the routes for volunteers are messed up.

### Question

So my question is, is there any way to have the `current_user` helper, refer to another model other than user?

Comment: Have you using the cancan authorization gem?

Comment: @Suborx, Declarative authorization, but it's heavily extended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this way you allow a user to be signed in as a User and a Voluteer in the same session.

Once you have a way to deal with that could you not just have

```
# in application_controller.rb
alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
def current_user
  devise_current_user || current_volunteer
end
```

in your application_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and solved it like this. But is this solution is specific for cancan gem.

application_controlller.rb

```
def actual_user
  @actual_user ||= current_user.present? ? current_user : current_volunteer
end

def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(actual_user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted viktor tron's answer beacuse it seems the cleanest method.

However, i have resolved my issue in a different way.

I've ended up hardcoding the sign in process for other classes as `:user`. This gives me access to the `current_user` method even for the volunteer class.

```
class Volunteers::SessionsController < Users::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    if resource
      flash[:notice] = "You are logged in"
      sign_in(:user, resource)
      super
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a little to late but you can try the following in your routes.rb

```
devise_for :users , :skip => :registrations
as :user do
    match "volunteers/edit(.:format)", :to => "devise/registrations#edit"
end
devise_for :volunteers , :skip => :sessions
```

The above code assumes that all users and its subclasses (assuming what you are implementing STI to achieve Users model hierarchy) can sign_in and sign_out, but only volunteers can register. Since a volunteer is a user, the user should be able to edit his registration as such. You can add more routes inside the as :user block.