# Rails: NoMethodError in ItemsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am receiving an error when accessing `@favorites = current_viewer.favorites_items.where(item_id: @item.id)` from my `ItemsController`:

```
NoMethodError in ItemsController#show 
undefined method `favorites_items' for nil:NilClass
```

items_controller.rb

```
 def show
   @favorites = current_viewer.favorites_items.where(item_id: @item.id)
   @comments = Comment.where(item_id: @item).order("created_at DESC")
   @items = Item.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Model associations:

```
class Viewer < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorites
 has_many :favorite_items, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Item'

end

class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :viewer
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :seller
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  mount_uploaders :attachments, ImageUploader
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :viewers, controllers: {registrations: 'viewers/registrations', sessions: 'viewers/sessions'}
  devise_scope :viewer do
    get "viewers/index"=> "viewers/sessions#index", :as => "viewer_index"
  end

get '/favorites', to: 'favorite_items#index', as: 'favorites'
resources :favorite_items, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Update 1

I typed next three times with byebug:

```
40: 
41:   # GET /items/1
42:   # GET /items/1.json
43:   def show
44:     byebug
=> 45:     @favorites = current_viewer.favorites_items.where(item_id: @item.id)
46:     @comments = Comment.where(item_id: @item).order("created_at DESC")
(byebug)

in /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb
17: 
18:     private
19:       def process_action(*args)
20:         super
21:       rescue Exception => exception
=> 22:         request.env["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"] ||= show_detailed_exceptions?
23:         rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
24:       end
25:   end
26: end
(byebug) 

18:     private
19:       def process_action(*args)
20:         super
21:       rescue Exception => exception
22:         request.env["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"] ||= show_detailed_exceptions?
=> 23:         rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
24:       end
25:   end
26: end
(byebug)
```

Comment: You didn't define `current_viewer`.

Comment: Since you are using devise you should be using current_viewer

Comment: @Gabriel Mesquita... its just a typo on the question, I changed it now

Comment: Yes i saw it. current_viewer is nil you need to define it

Comment: @Gabriel Mesquita... and how can I define the `current_viewer`?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549038/the-same-current-user-on-multiple-models-in-devise where is your devise_for in routes.rb?

Comment: I think is because of your devise_for call. Post your routes.rb so I can post an answer to help you. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1757

Comment: @ Gabriel Mesquita... I just update my question with the devise routes. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to use a byebug? Can you put a byebug before the @favorites call and check if current_viewer is nil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156382/discussion-between-gabriel-mesquita-and-theopap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have different kinds of users roles, you need to access your helper correctly like this:

```
def show
   if current_viewer
    @favorites = current_viewer.favorites_items.where(item_id: @item.id)
   elsif
    @favorites = current_seller.favorites_items.where(item_id: @item.id)
   end
   @comments = Comment.where(item_id: @item).order("created_at DESC")
   @items = Item.find(params[:id])
 end
```

the current_viewer helper was nil, because you were logged in as a seller!

Comment: I had to get rid of the `?` on the `if current_viewer` an error appeared suggesting this... and now there is an error on `elsif` line: `undefined method 'favorites_items' for #<Seller:0x007fa22fbb6dd0>`

Comment: @Theopap viewer has this  has_many :favorite_items, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Item' , does seller has too?

Comment: I also had to change `favorites_items` to `favorite_items` and I'm getting this: undefined method `favorite_items' for nil:NilClass... hmmmm weird

Comment: Makes sense, since you have this: has_many :favorite_items . not favorites :) This nilClass is happening with viewer or seller?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set before filter to authenticate viewer

```
class ItemsController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_viewer!

  def show
   ...
  end
end
```